# 'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, cmd, cygwin, environment-variables

So I am having trouble with running the 'android' command in cmd.
It was working originally I had set up the environment variables and it worked fine but after a reboot the variables were cleared and even after they had been re-added them it still didn't work. Currently, I have added the path to both tools, and platform-tools to the PATH environment variable. I have also searched everywhere for a cygwin fold in case that got install and is causing the problems but I cannot find any trace of such folder so I don't think it is that. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solve... No idea why but the PATH environment variable went all messed so I had to to go into cmd and use

```html
setx PATH ""
```

to clear it then add the variables agin. No idea why this happened but that fixed it.